Visual Studio Crashes When Adding LINQ to SQL .dbml File and Dragging Table from SQL Server Object Explorer
I'm encountering a persistent issue with Visual Studio, and I'm hoping for some guidance. Whenever I try to add a LINQ to SQL class (.dbml file) and drag a table from the SQL Server Object Explorer, Visual Studio crashes immediately. Additionally, I'm frequently receiving an error related to connection properties.
Development Environment:

Visual Studio 2022 (latest update)
.NET Framework 4.8
SQL Server 2019
Windows 11

Basically This error come after I am trying to connect the data source to SQL server
I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any advice or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
NOTE : I need to connect the datasource directly without giving the connectionstring into web.config

Tried to Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio
Tried to add the connection string into the web.config and its working with manually add
Also I have Tried with the SQL Connection Provider From NewGate
Cleaned and rebuilt the solution multiple times.
No Extra Extension Was Downloaded
Attempted to create the .dbml file manually, but Visual Studio still crashes upon dragging tables.
I've also tried using Entity Framework Core as an alternative to LINQ to SQL, but encountered configuration issues.


I have conducted relevant tests, but the error you encountered did not occur. Perhaps you can try to obtain relevant logs to analyze the cause of the problem. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 and enter the command:
devenv /log "\Path_to_store_logs\xxx.xml"  After opening VS here, reproduce the problem, and finally close VS, which will generate the log.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Aenn4Wy9wlQhCBUhrTd13Cvl61ihhNo/view?usp=drive_link

In the log you provided, the error information is basically about the invalid assembly names or missing version information of various System.Windows.Forms and other components. You can confirm whether the relevant dll does exist based on the relevant dll path in the error message. If it is indeed missing, try reinstalling .NET Desktop Development and ASP.NET and Web Development workloads.
